# Find the closed form of the the sums:

Tags: arithmetic, mobius-function

I am trying to find the closed form of the following sums:

a) $$\sum_{r|d}\mu(r)\tau\left(\frac{n}{r}\right)$$
b) $$\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)\sigma\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)$$
c) $$\sum_{r|n}\mu(r)\tau(r)$$
d) $$\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)\sigma(d)$$

For a), I suspect that we have $1^k$ ($k$ is the quantity of the divisors of $n$).

For b), we just have $n$.

I am hoping to prove this, but I got stuck.

Comment: I suspect you're getting downvoted because people find this question to be too vague/carelessly written. I upvoted to counterbalance, but the question may get closed if too many people dislike it - so I suggest editing in some detail and context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to reverse the [Möbius inversion formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula) to evaluate the first two of these. It says that if $f$ and $g$ are arithmetic functions such that $$g(n)=\sum_{d|n}f(d)$$ then $$f(n)=\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)g(n/d)$$

If you can guess the correct answer, this formula will make proving correctness easy.

Comment: I proved that the function is multiplicative, then I think I got the correct answer. Thanks for the help.